# Changes don't appear in Unstaged changes

Tags: eclipse, git

I've got a problem with my java project.

I have imported the project from bitbucket, it works great.

But, when I create a new class, It doesn't appear in the Unstagged changes.

I did search by myself, and I found that : 
[image]

So my class is a ignored ressource, I want it to be not ignored.

Comment: edit .gitignore file and remove the entry which is pointing to your class and refresh your project and try to commit your changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on file and navigate to Team => Add. The question mark will turn into a plus symbol and the file will be tracked by Git, but it is not yet committed. All of the file’s parent folders should now have a symbol that looks like an asterisk indicating that it is ‘staged’. In the next commit, the file will be added to the repository and the plus symbol will turn into a repository icon. The repository icons of all the file’s parents (packages/project…) will turn into staged icons. EGit also allows selecting untracked files to be added in the commit dialog if you turn on the option “Show untracked files”. In this case, they will be added and committed at the same time. [image]

Comment: hello, thanks for your fast answering, so I did your manipulations, but I don't find the Add option :/, I have a Add to index option, but when I click on it, It doesn't change anything.

You said that there is another option ? Can you show me how to do it please ?

There is a image of what I got when I do the manipulation : 
http://prnt.sc/eyv48r

Thank you a lot for your help, I'm sorry for this dumb question

Comment: Yes do "Add to Index", Thank "commit" and than "Push" which will upload your file in repo.

Answer (score 0):

So finally the solution was a part of 2 answers (Ardeshana Milan and funnyfox).

In the first time, when I press the Add to index button, it doesn't change anything.

So I applied the funnyfox's solution, I deleted the line into gitignore file.

Then, I did the Ardeshana Milan's solution once again, and It did work.