# Java Eclipse: creating new class but doesn't show git staging

Tags: java, git, eclipse, github, commit

I am working for first time on a shared java project via github.

this morning I've created a new class and new package with a class in it to commit, but they doesn't appears in the git staging. I tried some things like clicking add to index in the Git Repository view, change preferences of eclipse but nothing.. i don't really know why those classes can't be committed.

Leave here a screenshot of the project:

Eclipse image:

[image]

Thanks everyone

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528891/changes-dont-appear-in-unstaged-changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: thank you guys, the link of manoj solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible situation:

1. Maybe the parent Directory is writed in .gitignore，please check it out;
2. Maybe you need use `git add -A` in terminal to add them in stage area.